# Jquery not working in IE9 RC

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have just upgraded to IE9 RC (which i must add isnt too bad an attempt by microsoft, so far, they still have time to mess it up! *Please dont comment below on how wonderful/rubbish you think it is, I dont want a browser war!*) in order to test websites.

Now I understand its only a release candidate, and is still being developed, but for some reason none of jQuery on my site is not being rendered properly (I say not rendering properly, I really mean not working fullstop).

The only way to get it to work is to use IE9 Browser Mode and IE8 Standards.
Using IE9 Broswer Mode and IE9 Standards stops the jQuery working.

I understand im probably going to have to wait until they either ugrade IE or the jQuery API but does anyone know why this is or possibly have a fix?

Cheers guys!

**UPDATE**

Ok so then guys you can either go back to jQuery V1.4 or use this release candidate of jQuery v1.5 - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1rc1.js

Comment: May I suggest that you use the developer extension and see what's causing all the trouble by turning on the javascript debugging? You can do it by pressing `F12`, selecting the `Script` tab and pressing the `Enable Debugging` button.

Comment: [This bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052), perhaps?

Comment: @Igor Zinov'yev - breaking at this point - `srcElements = elem.getElementsByTagName("*");` Just to note im using jQuery v1.5. thanks

Comment: I assume @Ryano is talking about something specific like FancyBox? - which doesn't work at all... (in IE9)

Comment: @lonesomeday - thats the one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1rc1.js

That should help ;)

Comment: Why is this flaged as Answer when it was not?

Comment: It was.... Some features of jQuery 1.5 didn't work for IE9... not anymore, thanks to 1.5.1 > ....

Answer (score 4):

First off check if some of your code is incorrect in your `$(document).ready()`. if that all looks fine reload your page and hit F12 click the script tab then click start debugging and it will reload the page and halt it with a break point at your error in javascript.

jQuery does work in IE9 RC I use it myself for testing.

However if your doing some thing IE don't support near the top of your `$(document).ready()` it could be preventing the rest of the page from loading.

If this is down to `console.log` there is a good way to prevent IE from haling of `console.log`:

```
if(console == undefined){ console = {log:function(){}}; }
```

Comment: Thanks - nice answer - I had a Chrome-specific call to console.log() which was breaking IE9 but worked fine under the IE debugger.

Comment: Your "workaround" would be more conventional if started like `if (!console)`.

Comment: @Unihedron the only problem with that is you would have to put it before every console.log my way you can stick it at the top of the JS file and then you can just use console.log normally.

Comment: Well it is you can use it normally it just wont do anything. i was more meaning your calls can be there normally not requiring an `if` statement before every call.

Answer (score 2):

I used IE9 on my laptop at my old job and it worked fine with jquery. And I was just listening in on the jquery dev meeting a couple of days ago and even on that they mentioned that only a couple of test cases fail. You may be having some other issue, maybe a security setting or something.

Comment: It works when you have IE8 standards set, but IE9 standards breaks the jQuery. Others in my office on IE9 have the same issue.

Comment: Hmmm. well, we use it for testing as well and we've never run into any problems. The query team would know about it if it was broke like that. Weird environment issue?

Comment: It may be because you are using a version of jQuery before v1.5, 1.4 seems to work fine! Thanks you your help anyways!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.5 had some troubles with IE9. I switched back to latest 1.4 and works ok.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `getElementsById` tag, you'll need to use the [Release Candidate](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1rc1.js) as this has fixed the issue.