# Google Recaptcha not working in IE9

Tags: html, .net, recaptcha

I have a recaptcha that's works only works once in every 20 referesh of page or sometimes changing the browser mode to compatibility view. I have tried these META tags but still not working. Any solution?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Comment: You may run in to issues as it's not supported on IE9 https://support.google.com/recaptcha/answer/6223828?hl=en. Do you get any errors if the console?

Comment: @phuzi I am getting this error is console just in IE9  `SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined. gtm.js?id=GTM-MPB22L, line 63 character 380` but i have JQuery loaded in the page

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using this Jquery 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1rc1.js.

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103414/6754980

Comment: What version of jQuery were you using?

Comment: @phuzi version 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Google recaptcha does not work in IE compatibility mode. You'll experience this mode while trying to emulate specific versions of IE.